# Stop function Corona SDK

Tags: ios, lua, coronasdk

I am trying to make it so that on an incorrect collision my function of spawning objects stops, and all the variables (score), restart back to their default (0).  That way, when the player touches the screen again the game is ultimately re-started and the spawn() function begins again.

My code contains the tap event to start the spawning, the spawning function, and the collision.
I had difficulty getting it to format properly above, but here is the code on Hastebin: http://hastebin.com/edotuwokon.lua

Thanks!

Comment: You can cancel the timer with `timer.cancel(timerID)`, see [Corona Docs](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/cancel.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would have a separate function that stops your timer and resets anything you need to reset, like this:

```
function stopSpawn()
    timer.cancel(timerHandle)
    score = 0
    -- do anything else that needs to happen
end
```

And then call it from your `objCollision` function as needed.